# How to handle errors in django views?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view to log in and when the user does not exist it throws me an error, I would like this error to be printed in the template, saying that the user does not exist, try this way but it does not work for me. Would there be any other way to make it work?

**View**

```
def login_rfid(request):
'''
Login
'''

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = ''
    if 'username' in request.POST:
        print("sasrfwrfsrsf")
        rfid = request.POST['username']

        user = User.objects.get(rfid=rfid)

        if user is not None:
            user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'The user does not exist')
return render(request, "registration/login_rfid.html")
```

**HTML**

```
{% if messages %}
    <div class="span12">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message|safe }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Ok i didnt understand why u wrote username=''
in beggining of the function but heres the code which will work for u

```
def login2(request):
    # Check if the user is already logged in or not
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/service-page.html")

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/service-page.html")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Invaild Credentials, Please try again")
            return render(request,"login.html")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Only POST Methods are allowed baby")
    return HttpResponse("Wrong password")
```